# Solving an equation in a noncommutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is noncommutative ring with unit and has the properties necessary for a right and left skew field of fractions to exist (i.e. $R$ has no zero divisors and satisfies the left and right Ore condition). Let $x,y\in R$ be nonzero elements in $R$ so that $x,y$ are prime and $xy=yx$ in $R$.

I am interested in showing that the solutions to the equation 
$$xp+yq=0 $$
are exactly $p=yt, q=-xt$ for all $t\in R$.

Here is my reasoning:

$p=q=0$ is a solution. Now consider all other solutions.

If we assume one of $p$ or $q$ is nonzero, then since there are no zero divisors in $R$, we know both $p$ and $q$ are nonzero. In the skew field of fractions we can rewrite the equation as
$$p=-x^{-1}yq $$
but since  $x$ and $y$ commute, we have
$$p=-yx^{-1}q. $$
Since the left side resides in $R$ if seems like $q=xt$ for some $t\in R$, since $y$ can not contain a factor of $x$ by the primeness assumption. By a similar argument, we can conclude that $p=ys$ for some $s\in R$. Hence the equation becomes 
$$xys+yxt=0 .$$
Multiplying on the left by $x^{-1}y^{-1}$ yields 
$s=-t$ Proving the result.

I feel I may be making a mistake. Some of the steps may not work in such a general setting? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a "prime" in a non-commutative ring? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138350/prime-elements-in-a-noncommutative-ring).

Comment: I'm using the notion of prime given in Cohn's paper which appears in your link, i.e.  an element is prime if it cannot be written as the product of two nonunits.

Comment: A right Ore domain does not have to be Noetherian on either side... where’d you get that?

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re rejecting $p=q=0$ as a solution... when you say “since there are no zero divisors.”  And you didn’t use your primeness assumption? Fishy.

Comment: The left (right) Noetherian was overkill. I recall that left (right) Noetherian implies the left (right) Ore condition is satisfied. In my case I'm interested in $R$ a skew Laurent polynomial ring, in which case I believe $R$ satisfies these stronger conditions. My apologies. I should have mentioned that above.

Comment: I forgot to mention the solution $p=q=0$. Thanks for pointing that out. I also noted were I thought I needed the primeness. I needed it to ensure that $y$ does not have a factor of $x$ and similarly $x$ does not have factor of $y$.